# docker permission denied running from php

Tags: php, docker, exec

I am running a php script which runs a exec() function to run a docker container.

i echo my user via php

```
exec("whoami  2>&1",$out);
                            var_dump($out);
```

it shows deamon.
The code i am trieng to run is:

```
exec("docker run --rm -d -i -t -v ".$targetPath.":/user threed sh /user/test.sh 2>&1",$out);
                            var_dump($out);
```

but the error i got is

```
string(237) "docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.38/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied."   [2]=>   string(24) "See 'docker run --help'. "
```

can any one help me out to run docker container from my php script.

Comment: i tried but 
sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" /home/"$USER"/.docker -R
sudo chmod g+rwx "/home/$USER/.docker" -R

what to put in place of user??

Comment: Something which might be of interest is to have a look at https://github.com/docker-php/docker-php.  This brings an API to PHP which allows you to control Docker.

Comment: nops its adding to much burden to my app

Comment: yes that part is gone i read official documentation it says
To fix this problem, either remove the ~/.docker/ directory (it is recreated automatically, but any custom settings are lost),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related to the user running your PHP code.
First you need to determinate which user is running the PHP code. Is it your user?, is it php-fpm? www-data?
After that you need to add that user to the docker user group. More info on this in the following link: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/